# bad_alloc identifier not recognized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, syntax, compiler-errors, bad-alloc

I'm getting a compiler error:

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bad_alloc'

I've used the chunk of code below in other projects before, with different memory allocation within the try block, without problems. I was hoping someone could explain to me why bad_alloc isn't being recognized by VS10 despite it not causing the same problem in use in other programs? Odds are I missed some minor syntactical thing, but I've spent hours trying to figure it out, and at this point I feel like I'm probably blind to the error. Thanks for the help!

```
try
{
    node* tbr = new node();
    return tbr;
} // End try allocation

catch(bad_alloc)
{
     throw OutOfMemoryException();
} // End catch(bad_alloc)
```

Comment: do you have `using namespace std` in your code? if not, try `catch(std::bad_alloc)`.

Comment: As stellarossa suggests, the exception type is actually named `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bad_alloc is defined in the header new.

```
#include <new>
```

In namespace std.

```
using namespace std
```

Comment: This ended up working perfectly, so thank you to arjenz and stellarossa. However, I'm curious as to why it would have caused a problem in this class but not in the other. Obviously its hard to answer a question like that without looking at the other code, but I didn't have any standard libraries included in the other class, nor did I use namespace std.